# Copying large files I get the error "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: windows-server-2003

When copying and pasting large files I often get this error and nothing I have tried has resolved the issue.

This occurs on a Windows Storage Server 2003 SP2 32-bit server. The machine has 2-gb of RAM (older server and was deployed before I worked here).

Any ideas?

Comment: About how large is the file?

Comment: Are you copying files over the network? How large are the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a similar issue, and ran across this KB article yesterday - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304101/en-us.

The article discusses fixing an issue when trying to backup large volumes; but when you read the details, it seems like it could be related (Insufficient system resources exist to complete the reqeusted service).

The article describes a way to check your system is affected by the issue, and some registry changes that may correct the behavior

I have not implemented this yet.  The issue occurs only on a production system (the dev is unaffected).  We are still assessing.

Might be helpful to you...

Comment: I've had the exact same problem on a now retired Server 2003 box, Non paged kernel memory exhaustion was the problem, specifically the Mmst tag, as per the article.